# Postfix DSN=5.0.0 (domain.com) status=bounced

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I installed and configured the groupware ZIMBRA on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The mails between our company's network (@abc.de) and ZIMBRA (@123.de) works fine. Since we wanted to test ZIMBRA, we dug up an old domain (@123.de) which was used some time ago. To make sure that ALL e-mails with the @123.de domain dont get lost, i created a mail address where all the @123.de mails would be collected.

So I connected to the ZIMBRA host via telnet to test if I can send emails - without success. I include the maillog and the postfix postconf:

```
May 15 12:39:35 ubuntuvm postfix/postscreen[22013]: CONNECT from [192.168.0.XXX]:50168 to [192.168.0.XXX]:25
May 15 12:39:35 ubuntuvm postfix/postscreen[22013]: WHITELISTED [192.168.0.XXX]:50168
May 15 12:39:35 ubuntuvm postfix/smtpd[22014]: connect from ubuntuvm.123.de[192.168.0.XXX]
May 15 12:40:00 ubuntuvm postfix/smtpd[22014]: NOQUEUE: filter: RCPT from ubuntuvm.123.de[192.168.0.XXX]: <user@abc.de>: Sender address triggers FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026; from=<user@abc.de> to=<aaabbb@123.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<123.de>
May 15 12:40:00 ubuntuvm postfix/smtpd[22014]: 2C7A5101E93: client=ubuntuvm.123.de[192.168.0.XXX]
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/cleanup[22024]: 2C7A5101E93: message-id=<20180515104000.2C7A5101E93@ubuntuvm.123.de>
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 2C7A5101E93: from=<user@abc.de>, size=353, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[22562]: connect from localhost.123.de[127.0.0.1]
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/dkimmilter/smtpd[22562]: 750D8101E95: client=localhost.123.de[127.0.0.1]
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/cleanup[22024]: 750D8101E95: message-id=<20180515104000.2C7A5101E93@ubuntuvm.123.de>
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 750D8101E95: from=<user@abc.de>, size=839, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/smtp[22560]: 2C7A5101E93: to=<aaabbb@123.de>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=19, delays=19/0/0.01/0.12, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10030): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 750D8101E95)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 2C7A5101E93: removed
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/amavisd/smtpd[22565]: connect from localhost.123.de[127.0.0.1]
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/amavisd/smtpd[22565]: 9E6A5101E93: client=localhost.123.de[127.0.0.1]
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/cleanup[22024]: 9E6A5101E93: message-id=<20180515104000.2C7A5101E93@ubuntuvm.123.de>
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 9E6A5101E93: from=<user@abc.de>, size=1418, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/smtp[22564]: 750D8101E95: to=<aaabbb@123.de>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10032, delay=0.18, delays=0.05/0/0.01/0.12, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 9E6A5101E93)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 750D8101E95: removed
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/error[22566]: 9E6A5101E93: to=<aaabbb@123.de>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (123.de)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/cleanup[22024]: A6614101E96: message-id=<20180515104009.A6614101E96@ubuntuvm.123.de>
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/bounce[22567]: 9E6A5101E93: sender non-delivery notification: A6614101E96
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: A6614101E96: from=<>, size=3219, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 15 12:40:09 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: 9E6A5101E93: removed
May 15 12:40:17 ubuntuvm postfix/smtp[22568]: A6614101E96: to=<user@abc.de>, relay=mail.abc.de[192.168.0.X]:25, delay=7.4, delays=0/0.01/0.02/7.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 w4FAeB8o029287 Message accepted for delivery)
May 15 12:40:17 ubuntuvm postfix/qmgr[19016]: A6614101E96: removed
May 15 12:41:43 ubuntuvm postfix/amavisd/smtpd[19862]: timeout after END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost.123.de[127.0.0.1]


address_verify_negative_refresh_time = 10m
address_verify_poll_count = ${stress?3}${stress:5}
address_verify_poll_delay = 3s
address_verify_positive_refresh_time = 12h
alias_maps = lmdb:/etc/aliases
allow_mail_to_commands =
allow_mail_to_files =
always_add_missing_headers = yes
bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
bounce_queue_lifetime = 5d
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
canonical_maps = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-canonical.cf
command_directory = /opt/zimbra/common/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /opt/zimbra/common/libexec
data_directory = /opt/zimbra/data/postfix/data
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_process_limit = 100
delay_warning_time = 0h
header_checks =
hopcount_limit = 50
html_directory = no
import_environment =
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
lmdb_map_size = 16777216
lmtp_connection_cache_destinations =
lmtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 4s
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
lmtp_tls_CAfile =
lmtp_tls_CApath =
lmtp_tls_ciphers = export
lmtp_tls_exclude_ciphers =
lmtp_tls_loglevel = 0
lmtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
lmtp_tls_security_level = may
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = igor@123.de
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /opt/zimbra/common/sbin/mailq
manpage_directory = /opt/zimbra/common/share/man
max_use = 100
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 5d
message_size_limit = 10240000
meta_directory = /opt/zimbra/common/conf
milter_command_timeout = 30s
milter_connect_timeout = 30s
milter_content_timeout = 300s
milter_default_action = tempfail
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = 123.de
myhostname = ubuntuvm.123.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
mynetworks_style = subnet
newaliases_path = /opt/zimbra/common/sbin/newaliases
non_smtpd_milters =
notify_classes = resource, software
postscreen_access_list = permit_mynetworks
postscreen_bare_newline_action = ignore
postscreen_bare_newline_enable = no
postscreen_bare_newline_ttl = 30d
postscreen_blacklist_action = ignore
postscreen_cache_cleanup_interval = 12h
postscreen_cache_retention_time = 7d
postscreen_command_count_limit = 20
postscreen_dnsbl_action = ignore
postscreen_dnsbl_max_ttl = ${postscreen_dnsbl_ttl?{$postscreen_dnsbl_ttl}:{1}}h
postscreen_dnsbl_min_ttl = 60s
postscreen_dnsbl_reply_map =
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 1
postscreen_dnsbl_ttl = 1h
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = 0
postscreen_greet_action = ignore
postscreen_greet_ttl = 1d
postscreen_non_smtp_command_action = drop
postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = no
postscreen_non_smtp_command_ttl = 30d
postscreen_pipelining_action = enforce
postscreen_pipelining_enable = no
postscreen_pipelining_ttl = 30d
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol =
postscreen_watchdog_timeout = 10s
postscreen_whitelist_interfaces = static:all
propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical
queue_directory = /opt/zimbra/data/postfix/spool
queue_run_delay = 300s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter =
relayhost =
sample_directory = /opt/zimbra/common/conf
sender_canonical_maps =
sendmail_path = /opt/zimbra/common/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = no
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_dns_support_level = enabled
smtp_fallback_relay =
smtp_generic_maps =
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext,noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile =
smtp_tls_CApath =
smtp_tls_ciphers = export
smtp_tls_dane_insecure_mx_policy = dane
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols =
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_transport_rate_delay = $default_transport_rate_delay
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_auth_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_port_logging = no
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_milters =
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 100s
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_client_hostname, permit
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = no
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/opt/zimbra/common/conf/tag_as_originating.re, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_tls_clientcerts, check_sender_access regexp:/opt/zimbra/common/conf/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_CAfile =
smtpd_tls_CApath =
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 9
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /opt/zimbra/conf/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = export
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /opt/zimbra/conf/dhparam.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers =
smtpd_tls_key_file = /opt/zimbra/conf/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_enable = no
tls_append_default_CA = no
transport_maps = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-transport.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_defer_code = 250
virtual_alias_domains = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-vad.cf
virtual_alias_expansion_limit = 10000
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-vam.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-vmd.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-vmm.cf
virtual_transport = error
```

I also used the `luser_relay` option, because all mails with the @123.de domain should be guided towards a static address and the `local_recipient_maps =`option so that all mails are accepted. 
Somehow, my `relayhost`always gets overwritten after I reboot the VM. I think this is intended and must be kept empty. right?

Thanks in advance and please, guide me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution after a long time searching forums and contacting the ZIMBRA support. In case of anyone stumbling across the same problem, I'll leave my fix here.

```
zmprov modifyAccount dump@123.de zimbraMailCatchAllAddress @123.de
```

To summarize this: you need this operation (as the ZIMBRA user) for collecting all the incoming mails from unknown addresses with the @123.de domain.